# How to run add and run EF7 migrations using old project type

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to use EF7 with the old project type (csproj)

If I run Add-Migration in package manager, it complains that it cannot find package EntityFramework. I guess it is looking for the EF6 EntityFramework project, since such a project does not exist anymore? How can I force it to use EF7 Add-Migration cmdlet?

I have tried running ef commands with dnx in the "wrap" folder, but that seems needlessly complicated and it doesn't work (it cannot find any framework dependencies at all)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you [file a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new)? We may want to look into enabling this scenario...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed EntityFramework.Commands? https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework.commands

Also, using EF6 and EF7 in the same solution is going to cause some problems. It's probable that `Add-Migration` failed because you are actually running the EF6 command. Check if the command `Use-DbContext` exists, which is new to EF7.